# How to write a Vec of structs to a file?

Tags: rust

I have the following struct:

```
pub struct Employee {
     id: i128,
     pub name: String,
     pub department: String,
}
```

Part of my application collects `Employee` structs into a vector for storage. I would like to write all the `Employee` structs in the vector to a file. My plan was to do the following:

```rust
let mut directory = File::create("employee.txt").expect("unable to make file");

for e in &employees {
    directory.write(e).expect("cannot write data");
}
```

Unfortunately `write` only takes `&[u8]` and I'm totally flummoxed on how to approach this problem. It doesn't seem possible to convert the struct values to `&[u8]` and I'm unsure if extracting each value within the struct to write them to the file is possible.

Comment: https://crates.io/crates/uuid